# I need a popup help file for Vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

Is there some kind of plugin or mode that can be used to display some help for commands? I am increasingly finding nano inadequate. I want to be come a hardcore Vim and Emacs user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ vimtutor` for starters.

I remember Emacs has a tutorial of some sort from back when I was choosing an editor, but I don't remember what it is.

I'd say learn enough about both to be able to function, then pick one or the other and master it (as much as possible--I'm finding after 7 years of using Vim that there's always lots to learn).

Answer (score 2):

`vimtutor` is an excellent tutorial for you to go through.

Also the built-in help in vim is very nice. Use `:help` inside vim for explanation about practically anything related to vim.

And of course there's [Vigor](http://vigor.sourceforge.net/), a User Friendly cartoon turned into reality. :-)